# Adding a listener for canceling selection in ListView (JavaFX)

Tags: java, listview, javafx, javafx-8

Nowadays I am practicing JavaFX. And I have a problem about ListView. I can make a listener for multiple selections of ListView. However, when I cancel the selection, the listener I made doesn't reflect the cancellation. How can I make a listener that reflects it? The following is a listener that I made.

```
ListView<String> lv = new ListView<>(FXCollections.observableArrayList(stringArray));  // stringArray is an array that I made.

lv.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener(ch -> {
        System.out.println("size: " + lv.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndices().size());
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

For changes in selection when multiple selections are enabled, add a `ListChangeListener` to the `selectedItems` list (note `selectedItems`, not `selectedItem`):

```
lv.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems().addListener(
    (ListChangeListener.Change<? extends String> ch) -> {
        System.out.println("size: " + lv.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndices().size());
    }
);
```

Note that if you are *only* interested in the selection being empty, you can do

```
Bindings.isEmpty(lv.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems()).addListener(
    (obs, selectionWasEmpty, selectionIsNowEmpty) -> {
        if (selectionIsNowEmpty) {
            System.out.println("Nothing is selected");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Something is selected");
        }
    }
);
```

Comment: To clarify @fabian's comment, which was posted before I edited the answer, an `InvalidationListener` would work on the `selectedItems` list (for fairly complex reasons), but might be triggered unnecessarily on the "empty binding" in the second code block (which was not there when fabian commented).